# Drawing panel to design a house

Tags: c#, java, layout, drawing

I need to know if there is an API or tool available whereby I can drop an object on the Java Form and in run time, the user can draw boxes, circles and different objects. Ideally, the user will be drawing a layout of a house, so icons which symbolise doors, windows, walls, radiators will be required. I don't mind whether this is in C# or Java.

Comment: There is no out of the box solution that will allow you to do this. But you could always write code and implement it.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("visio.exe")?

Comment: I like Adamski's solution.  Why don't you design your own API to do this?  Good, useful project.

Comment: @Adamski, my issue is that I need to also use the dimensions of the shapes drawn...etc to perform calculations and I have a limited amount of time to do this project - otherwise I would have designed my own API :(

Comment: Consider searching SourceForge or similar public repository for CAD libraries.

Comment: Do you really want to know how to program this, or do you just want to know about free house design/layout sofrware? Why reinvent the wheel when there's plenty of free CAD software out there that will do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only component I know of that will allow you to do what you want is Go-Diagram : http://www.nwoods.com/

But it's commercial and it costs.

I do however, have one idea for you.

As others have said, developing a panel that people can draw on is not at all difficult, but you also need to be able to work out areas, lengths and many other things.

People writing and using spatial and mapping apps have had this type of functionality for years using tool-kits like "Geos"

http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/

Now despite what you might think, Geos is an open source geometry engine, which means it's not just useful for spatial & gis calculations, it's also useful for regular geometry too.

I think, you could quite easily create a simple drawing panel using standard GDI+ techniques, and use Geos to do your calculations.

Of course, you could always look to things that have all ready been done.  DotSpatial is a spatial & mapping tool-kit for .NET, and again despite the name it's NOT just for displaying maps.

A big part of mapping is drawing and creating them too, which strikes me as not a million miles away from what your attempting to do.

Using DotSpatial as a starting point for modification, might get you up and running fairly quickly, and since it actually has drawing components in it along with all the geometric functions you'll ever need, then I think you might just be able to find elements of what you need contained within it.

You can get DotSpatial at Codeplex:

http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/